# Check shell Script copy Status

Tags: linux, backup, shell, cron, exit-code

I have a cron script and i need to adjust it;
Actually some clients are generating in a directory some files, my task is to backup that files to a tape, and i need to make a if then else

```
cp $files $tape
if exit 0 
     then 
        send successfully mail 
        delete files
     else 
         send a fail mail 
         but don't delete that files
fi
```

Could someone help me with that?

Maybe with something like that?
Actually the code is like that

```
    find $STR_FILES -print | backup -ivq -f $TAPE >> /tmp/logfile
```

you say that i must put something like that?

```
    BKP='find $STR_FILES -print | backup -ivq -f $TAPE'
    $BKP >> /tmp/logfile
    if [$BKP -eq 0 ]
       then
       ...
       else
       ...
    fi
```

?

Actually i did as a test

Actually i did
        cd /
        find /u01 -name ora_856562.aud

```
    if ["$?" = "0" ]; then
    rm /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/rdbms/audit/ora_856562.aud
    (echo "Se depuraron  *.aud Ok") | mail -r oracle_alfa@notification.imcl-peoplesoft.com -s "Prueba if"  egrc77@hotmail.com
    else
    (echo "NO Se depuraron  *.aud Ok") | mail -r oracle_alfa@notification.imcl-peoplesoft.com -s "Prueba if"  egrc77@hotmail.com
    fi
    exit
```

but fails with

```
    ./prueba.sh[3]: 0:  not found.
    ./prueba.sh[5]: [127:  not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously recommend you to user rsync for this task.

But back on topic, your script is almost done but you will need to fix a few things:

- The conditional needs to be fixed. You will needs something like:

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]

Read [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) about conditionals and such.

- You can easily send mail from CLI with one of several programs. I advise sendmail for it's ease of use. More [here](http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/01/how-to-send-email-from-the-linux-command-line/)

Comment: The mail script code i have and is working fine, 
actually the code is this

find $STR_FILES -print | backup -ivq -f $TAPE >> $TMP_LOG_DLS 

BKP='find $STR_FILES -print | backup -ivq -f $TAPE'

if [$BKP -eq 0 ]

?

Comment: the $? variable holds the exit status of the last command executed. You don't need to check the value of $BKP, just the exit status of the operation in which you you perform the backup

Comment: Actually i did as a test

Comment: Actually i did
        cd /
        find /u01 -name ora_856562.aud

        if ["$?" = "0" ]; then
        rm /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/rdbms/audit/ora_856562.aud
        (echo "Se depuraron  *.aud Ok") | mail -r oracle_alfa@notification.imcl-peoplesoft.com -s "Prueba if"  egrc77@hotmail.com
        else
        (echo "NO Se depuraron  *.aud Ok") | mail -r oracle_alfa@notification.imcl-peoplesoft.com -s "Prueba if"  egrc77@hotmail.com
        fi
        exit